# What do I need to know before using an HTTP proxy?

Tags: proxy, http

There is one web site I want to surf with an IP different than my own.  Presumably this is as simple as going to one of the browser tabs and using the IP of an existing proxy.

1. Where can I get a list of existing, working, reliable proxies?
2. How can I tell if a proxy is honest - that is, not stealing unencrypted passwords, etc?
3. Do proxies exist whereby my computer can use an HTTPS connection to the proxy (reducing the worry from item #2) but passes appropriate HTTP to the website I want to connect to?
4. I really only want to use the proxy for one particular web site. By using the proxy in, say, Firefox, I assume *all* traffic to any site then goes through the proxy? That's fine if I can use two browsers. Say I use Konqueror for my proxy using browser - will this not affect Firefox which I can continue to use normally?

Comment: I do not know much about proxy services, but the one thing I would do is to go http://www.whatismyip.com/ before I start using one, and after, to make sure the IP changed.

Comment: whatismyip.org is better, it gets straight to the point re your IP no other fluff. There may be one or two other sites that automatically whois your IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Where can I get a list of existing, working, reliable proxies?

the only one I know if, is mrhinkydink, though it'd be good to have other options too. Otherwise, some people use TOR..

You can use Elite Proxy Switcher to change, like if one has gone slow.

mrhinkydink has some SOCKS ones up which is an innovation.. But he could stop his service any time, he did stop for quite a while recently, but then restarted.

don't get expectations high re speed and reliability. it's just relative to other lists. There is http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/  but I think you'll find http://www.mrhinkydink.com/proxies.htm is faster and more reliable but it's relative and isn't likely to be like your regular browsing experience, certainly any one free proxy ip won't be reliably fast even for basic pages.

> 2) How can I tell if a proxy is honest - that is, not stealing unencrypted passwords, etc?

You can't really. but if it's a company you pay and  you have their details then there's some accountability perhaps, and they're less likely to steal, but still you can't know for sure.  Certainly not any free online proxy list.

> 3) Do proxies exist whereby my computer can use an HTTPS connection to the proxy (reducing the worry from item #2) but passes appropriate HTTP to the website I want to connect to?

maybe but still might not trust it..

> 4) I really only want to use the proxy for one particular web site. By using the proxy in, say, Firefox, I assume all traffic to any site then goes through the proxy? That's fine if I can use two browsers. Say I use Konqueror for my proxy using browser - will this not affect Firefox which I can continue to use normally?

They won't affect each other obviously.

You could use FoxyProxy to assign a specific proxy for a specific site.  Or you could use elite proxy switcher to switch universally.

Use http://www.whatismyip.org/  to make sure you are browsing with that proxy

Comment: Wow, that mrhinkydink disclaimer page is a little sobering.  Makes it sounds like you end up on every terrorist watch list just for using a proxy.

Comment: @Sean  They are not secure, but that said, maybe you're not sobor, his disclaimer page also says "Not intended for use in the operation of nuclear facilities". So you should see where he is using humour. But his main page http://www.mrhinkydink.com/proxies.htm is clear enough A disclaimer is possibly some kind of legal thing to cover himself.

Comment: I meant the main page.  In any case, thanks for the helpful answer.  I tried FoxyProxy and it does what I need (most of the time) and lets me use the proxy just for the site I want.

Comment: I don't have enough points to upvote you so I hope the best answer suffices for now.  I guess I will eventually have enough points to get back to you.  Thanks again.

Comment: @sean great,glad it helped, your rep points should increase as you ask qs, or answer them.I will get some points anyway from the accept.The main thing on any site or forum, is the content.. so both you and I have helped that.You can also post a Q n A yourself if u discover something.Joel Spolsky,the founder of stackoverflow actually recommended doing that no doubt since on any good tech site/forum the main thing is content(which helps not just one individual, but potentially lots of people), and educates other techies that didn't know.