# What do I need to know before building my own censor avoider? Trying to understand "http proxy" projects

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

My question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/q/314162/109803) but I am looking to build my own, preferably contributing to open source projects along the way. But before I begin I need some help understanding some meta concepts.

Over the years I have come across sites that are listed as “proxy avoidance and anonymizers” by my school censor.

Some of these proxy avoidance sites allow the ability to surf the Internet through their server. So if you wanted to go to a Wikipedia site such as this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiananmen_Square
```

…but it was blocked by your ISP you could go through the HTTP proxy site and still navigate Wikipedia. But the URL would look something like this instead:

```
http://example-http-proxy-site.com/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiananmen_Square
```

My question has two parts.

1. What are these sites really doing? I am calling it “http-proxy avoidance” but is that the accepted term for this service?
2. What resources would be required to create your own personal “http-proxy” hosted on your personal site if it is hosted with a “shared resource hosting?” Or would it be too intensive and need its own host?
3. What do I need to know before building my own censor avoider?

Comment: I guess the real goal of my project is to be able to do Google, Yahoo, Bing, and other searches when search engines are banned across the board.

Comment: I found this list of open source http proxies. They mostly seem to be abandoned or removed. proxies.xhaus.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "proxy avoidance and anonymizer" would be a server which sits between you and where you and the site you are trying to reach (but have been barred from) and gets the information for you, bypassing the block.  It would also filter out some information about you to the server making you more difficult to track.

1. These sites are acting as anonymous proxies.
2. Privoxy springs to mind.  Squid can be configured to do this, and 
   pretty much any other type of proxying.  There are no doubt plenty 
   of other services - and indeed it would not be that hard to write 
   your own variant using curl and PHP.
3. You need to know that if you are doing something worth scrutinising you
   will most likely get caught - moreso if you need to ask the question, 
   as there are a huge number of traps and gotchas.

There are alternatives which are probably more secure and less work which you should investigate, including using a VPN service, ToR, Tails - All of these are useful, but all have their drawbacks.